# Set window variable value in by a function

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

I want to set window.userName variable value by the function, but I fail:

```
function changeName(variable) {
 variable = "Bill";
}

changeName( window.userName );

console.log( window.userName ); // outputs undefined
```

How could I pass the window.userName variable reference to the function or what else you would suggest to do with it?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code snippet that shows you main idea of the action:

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Bill",
  "location": {
    "latitude": "12.4124",
    "human_address": {
      "address": "Blabla St. 13",
      "city": "Moscow"
    },
    "longitude" : "51.2512"
  }
},
{
  "name": "James",
  "location": {
    "human_address": {
      "city": "Moscow"
    }
  }
}];

var allColumns = {};

function loopInto(targetObj, obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (!(k in targetObj)) {
      targetObj[k] = true;
    }
    if (typeof obj[k] == "object") {
      if (targetObj[k] == true)
        targetObj[k] = {};
      loopInto(targetObj[k], obj[k]);
    }
  }
}

for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  for (var k in data[i]) {
    if (!(k in allColumns)) {
      allColumns[k] = true;
    }
    if (typeof data[i][k] == "object") {
      if (allColumns[k] == true)
        allColumns[k] = {};
      loopInto(allColumns[k], data[i][k]);
    }
  }
}

console.log( allColumns );
```

As you can see, I am able to pass `allColumns[k]` object by reference and then change its value through the `loopInto` function. But why am I unable to do the same with e.g. `window.allColumns` variable? If you try replace `allColumns` with `window.allColumns` it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason was not a window variable, there were some errors in a function related with JSON.parse() method...

However, if someone wants to loop through a JSON, take all property names from it and put into a new JSON variable (window.allColumns), here is the code that may help you:

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Bill",
  "location": {
    "latitude": "12.4124",
    "human_address": {
      "address": "Blabla St. 13",
      "city": "Moscow"
    },
    "longitude" : "51.2512"
  }
},
{
  "name": "James",
  "location": {
    "human_address": {
      "city": "Moscow"
    }
  }
},
{
  "entityname" : "Tarararararara",
  "location" : {
    "latitude" : "40.279644",
    "human_address": {
      "address": "Space",
      "city": "Mars",
      "state": "LA",
      "zip": "3"
    }
  }
}];

window.allColumns = {};

function strIsJSON(str) {
  try {
    JSON.parse(str);
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return typeof JSON.parse(str) == "object" ? true : false;
}

function loopInto(targetObj, obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (!(k in targetObj)) {
      targetObj[k] = true;
    }
    if (typeof obj[k] == "object" || strIsJSON(obj[k])) {
      if (targetObj[k] === true && typeof targetObj[k] != "object")
        targetObj[k] = {};
      if (typeof obj[k] == "object")
        loopInto(targetObj[k], obj[k]);
      else
        loopInto(targetObj[k], JSON.parse(obj[k]));
    }
  }
}
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  for (var k in data[i]) {
    if (!(k in window.allColumns)) {
      window.allColumns[k] = true;
    }
    if (typeof data[i][k] == "object" || strIsJSON(data[i][k])) {
      if (window.allColumns[k] === true && typeof window.allColumns[k] != "object")
        window.allColumns[k] = {};
      if (typeof data[i][k] == "object")
        loopInto(window.allColumns[k], data[i][k]);
      else
        loopInto(window.allColumns[k], JSON.parse(data[i][k]));
    }
  }
}

console.log( window.allColumns );
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all Javascript variables are passed by value, not by reference. (The sort-of-kind-of exception is objects.) That means that you essentially copy the *value* of the `window.userName` property. Modifying the `variable` variable within the function only has an effect within the function.

There is no way of altering this behaviour. The one thing you could do is to modify the function so that it ca
n take both an object and a property name. For instance:

```
function changeName(obj, prop) {
    obj[prop] = 'Bill';
}
```

Because objects *are* passed by reference (well, sort of), setting a property on an object within a function affects it outside as well. So you could do `changeName(window, 'userName')`.

But I wouldn't. The normal way of sending data from a function to the rest of a script is by `return`ing it. A more idiomatic approach would look like this:

```
function getName() {
    return "Bill";
}
window.userName = getName();
```

Comment: Please preview my edited question and let me know about your thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can not take a variable as parameter and assign a value to the variable directly in a function.

It is possible to take an object as parameter and change the object, but not assign some value with an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), like `=`.

You could separate object and property and take both, the first as reference and the second as string to the function and change the value with assignment.

```js
function changeName(reference, key) {
    reference[key] = 'Bill';
}

changeName(window, 'userName');
console.log(window.userName); // Bill
```